# Difficult terrain while flying

Tags: pathfinder-1e, terrain

I am playing a very specialized character. The goal is to use [Precipice Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/precipice-strike-combat/) with arcane trickster [surprise spells](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/arcane-trickster/#TOC-Surprise-Spells) feature. Since being on the ground naturally puts me at greater risk, I was wondering what ways were open to me to count as being in difficult terrain, hopefully ones that can be quickly turned on/off. As producing difficult terrain on the group is generally easy enough, I am more interest in other areas of terrain such as when flying. I honestly dont know if there is more than flying, walking, and swimming, but pathfinder is wide. I would be happy if the answer is able to provide it for just flying.

It has also been house ruled that I must be affected by the DT, so having the druid ability to walk in non-magical undergowth means that terrain would not work. Along with this the enemy just has to be in DT, does not need to be affected by it, and does not have to be the same source as the one I am in.

For more information I am in a gestalt game where I am a wizard rogue who then levels up in arcane trickster and magus. This links to questions Ive asked in the past about sneak attack damage on spells.

Comment: Are you intending to be flying when you are "counted as being in difficult terrain"? I feel like you left out some of that info from the body of your question. The only hint at your full plan is in the title.

Comment: You are correct, I forgot to include that into the body of the question, but its not just flying. I just need whatever terrain I am in (which usually is just ground or flying) to be difficult. Its also house ruled that I need to be affected by it so my speed is reduced, but the enemy doesnt need to be, just in it. Also does not have to be the same source of DT.

Comment: Are you sure arcane trickster is allowed?  Prestige classes that are mostly just combinations of existing classes, like arcane trickster or mystic theurge, are typically banned in gestalt.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet I went over my build very carefully with the dm, he knows what my goal is and the expected power level compared to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Effects that create three-dimensional areas of difficult terrain**

Wizard spells:
2nd level - [*web*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/web/)
4th level - [*gravel vortex*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/gravel-vortex/), [*ice storm*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/ice-storm/), [*lost passage*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/lost-passage-samsaran/), [*web cloud*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/web-cloud/)
5th level - [*impossible angles*](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Impossible%20Angles)

Magic Items:
[*Rod of gripping smoke*](https://aonprd.com/MagicRodsDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Rod%20of%20Gripping%20Smoke)

Comment: Thank you. Some good choices, but that rod looks to be the best of the lot for me.